# iTunes unable to stream podcast episodes in AAC (play only downloaded)

Tags: mp3, mime-types, itunes, aac, podcast

I want to create a podcast feed for both Apple and Android devices. I want to use AAC instead of MP3 (because of quality/size) - Android supports AAC natively. According to the [documentation from Apple](https://help.apple.com/itc/podcasts_connect/#/itcb54353390), and I tested it, `type` of `<enclosure>` cannot be AAC (iTunes do now show any episode in such podcast feed). Well, I replaced `audio/aac` to `audio/x-m4a` - while files remained the same raw AAC - success - iTunes show episodes. I tested such configuration on the few Android podcast fetcher, iOS native Podcasts app stream such files correctly. BUT **iTunes can play files from such feed only after downloading - without downloading I click again and again but nothing playing, no errors**.

I tried to put MP3 for a test with mime `audio/mpeg` - iTunes stream such podcast episodes correctly.

I tried to change mime type of every file on my server to `audio/x-m4a` and to `audio/mpeg` - iTunes can not stream too.

Is it possible somehow to stream AAC files on iTunes or I will need to downgrade to MP3?

Comment: Try putting your AAC inside an M4A container.

Comment: Oops, strange that yesterday I did not think about that. Perhaps I was unconsciously sure that Android cannot play M4A but in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) I found that can.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @VC.One - I tried M4A as a file container - I [found](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) that Android supports it too.

Looks like my m4a in somewhat incorrect - I tried m4a from another podcast and it works.